# I couldn't see Conflict tables in replication monitor SQL 2008 R2 in Merge Replication

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, replication, database-replication

I worked Merge Replication in SQL server 2008 R2 ,  in replication monitor i can't see Conflict table, i must to see conflict tables in "MSmerge_conflicts_info" , please help me, How to see Conflict tables in replication monitor? ,Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see the conflict tables from within Replication Monitor.

However, you can view the Conflict Viewer by right-clicking your Merge Publication in Object Explorer -> View Conflicts.

Alternatively, you can directly query MSmerge_conflicts_info.

For more information, see [View and Resolve Data Conflicts for Merge Publication (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152576.aspx) and [Microsoft Replication Conflict Viewer (Merge Replication)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189029.aspx).

Comment: I had seen Conflict Tables,on This Point before, but , in New Setup ,i couldn't see .i must go to Conflict Viewer or Merge_conflicts info  table, and select Conflict Server and .....